# jQuery $.ajax & PHP Email Progress Indicator

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, progress, indicator

I am developing a custom emailing system for one of my clients as an add on for the CMS I built that I give to my clients. I am using jQuery Ajax to send all the information to a PHP file that formats the email, sends a query to MySQL to get all the email address from the database, and the sends the emails using the mail(). This takes some time to do, and I am wanting the jQuery ajax to display a progress bar for each time the PHP script sends an email. I have searched for something that is similar to success: function() that receives data from the PHP script through JSON allowing jquery to update the progress of the emailing.

Does anyone have a suggestion for this? Something like this is preferable:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "example.com",
      data: {"test":"test","tester":"tester"},
      PROGRESS: function(data){
        $("div").html(data);
      },
      success: function(r){
        alert(r);
      }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the xhr object and attach an event listener to the *progress* event

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
            var p = e.loaded / e.total;
            // update your progress bar here..
        });
        return xhr;
    }
})
```

Comment: In order to get this working I needed to change the xhr.addEventListener("progress".... ) line to xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",....) - otherwise, this was a helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap this inside of a `setInterval()` function. You can search for **AJAX Polling**. But the idea here is that you cannot send information back periodically from the same PHP script while it is running, the `success` callback is only triggered ONCE, after the script has finished.